# Automatically refresh a user1's page when user2 updates/adds a record in database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

i am working on a simple web app using asp.net, sql server.
i am stuck at a point, my requirement is to automatically refresh a user1's page when user2 updates/adds a record in database through his page. both user1 and user 2 are accessing records from same table.
How to do this, please ?

Comment: Even on the desktop, this is a bad idea. However, is the user editing data, say a record and they want to see the date update from the other user? Or are you talking about some kind of say grid of data and the user is viewing this grid of data, and if new records are added by other users, then you want to see new rows appear? That idea is ok, but it really depends on what/when/where you want to see the updates from other users to occur.  If you talking about this occurring while editing a record at the same time, then this is messy at best, and I would avoid this design requirement.

Comment: If you're just displaying data then probably the best you can do is use a timer in the script of your page to make an AJAX call periodically to check for any changes and update the page accordingly. The server can't arbitrarily notify the user without a request from the browser to respond to. If they're editing then I would agree that it's a bad idea and you should just let them save, catch the concurrency exception, show them the new data and then ask them how to proceed.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a polled solution, @jmcilhinney - could easily use something like signalr so a browser *can* be notified by the server, but I know what you mean and you're dead right that this is a waste of time developing something that tries to keep everything in sync. Even sites as big as stackoverflow don't bother with it; they just give a note "someone else edited the question before you did, your edit must be more substantive than theirs"

Answer (score 0):

As jmc points out in the comments; you don't. You simply keep a track of when user1 and user2 think the row was changed (for example, each person downloads the row's updatedOn date) and then when the time comes to make the edit by user2, having waited too long and user1 edited the row already, then user2 issues an update like `UPDATE person SET name = @newname, updatedOn=getUtcDate() WHERE ID =@id and updatedOn = @updatedOnFromBefore`

Because each user knew the old updatedOn value, and then user1 gave the correct value when he made his edit, and his edit changed the updatedOn value to something else, now it means user2's attempt to edit the db will fail because the value user2 remembers for updatedOn is wrong.

At this point you can now show user2 their edits and you can query the db for the current state of the data and you can give user2 the choice of "take theirs, take mine or merge the two yourself manually" (you can even try and merge auto by detecting who changed what, but that's harder).  The main thing being that this isn't trying to keep 100 people looking at the data up to date all the time; it's just preventing version conflicts at the moment saves are made

This is called optimistic concurrency and here is presented as a simple example to get you to understand the process. DBS like SQLServer have specific mechanisms (rowversion) for doing this concurrency management - you can read about them if needs be, but it works in this basic way; that some part of the data user2 downloaded must still be the same to allow the edit to succeed

---

If you're writing some other system that is delivering real-time updates constantly for example a stock trading system that keeps prices up to date the moment they occur then you need to look at something like signalR, which allows a JavaScript app on the page to establish a permanent connection to the server so that any updates the server has to make available are pushed instantly to all the clients. I definitely wouldn't use it over optimistic concurrency for data saving but I would use it for eg implementing a chat room, news feed, stock prices etc

Comment: can someone explain me please "..could easily use something like signalr so a browser can be notified by the server, .."   what is this and how can it be done in asp.net?